# Generate .jar file and javadoc in ship.io

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration

I have a Gradle task which generate .jar file for my library as well as Javadocs:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath())
    destinationDir = file("$output javadoc/")
    //Suppress warnings that can cause fail build on continuous integration tools
    failOnError false
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete "$output $filename"
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into("$output")
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', "$filename")
}

//Dependent tasks will be executed first before executing requested task
makeJar.dependsOn(javadoc, clearJar, ':app:packageReleaseJar')
```

In the continues integration framework (ship.io) which I am using, after finishing makeJar task, I receive all the following from `/app/build/` in Artifacts:

```
tmp.zip Zip Archive 
intermediates.zip   Zip Archive 
generated.zip   Zip Archive 
myLib.jar       
classes.jar
```

But I just want to have a zip file includes `mylib.jar and javadocs`. Intermediated, generated, classes and temp is not desired. Do you know any solution for that?

**Addenda:**

I add another task to delete unwanted folders:

```
task releaseLib(type: Delete, dependsOn: makeJar) {
    delete 'build/generated/'
    delete 'build/intermediates/'
    delete 'build/outputs/'
    delete 'build/tmp/'
}
```

This solves problem, but if you have better suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is Edwin, and I'm an engineer with Ship.io.

Your understanding of how we build artifacts is exactly correct. We upload artifacts as soon as the Gradle task completes. If you want to clean up the artifacts, you'll need to do so exactly as you describe before the Gradle runs.

Feel free to reply here or in the support ticket you filed if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi @Edwin, thanks for your fast reply. I faced with another problem, which I created a new ticket for that. Would you please check it out : [Release a library using ship.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559548/release-a-library-using-ship-io-continues-integration-framework)