# Release a library using ship.io (continues integration framework)

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration

I have following tasks in build.gradle under app module in order to release a library as a `jar file` as well as `javadoc`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def filename = 'myLib.jar'
def output = "build/Lib-MobileFramework-Android.${version}/"

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath())
    destinationDir = file("$output javadoc/")
    //Suppress warnings that can cause fail build on continuous integration tools
    failOnError false
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete "$output $filename"
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into("$output")
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', "$filename")
}

//Dependent tasks will be executed first before executing requested task
makeJar.dependsOn(javadoc, clearJar, ':app:packageReleaseJar')

task copyApk(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':test:assembleRelease') {
    from(project(':test').file('build/outputs/apk/'))
    into("${output}TestApp/")
    include('test-release.apk')
    rename('test-release.apk', 'TestApp.apk')
}

task releaseLib(type: Delete, dependsOn: [makeJar, copyApk]) {
   delete project(':test').file('build/generated/')
   delete project(':test').file('build/outputs/')
   delete project(':test').file('build/tmp/')
   delete project(':test').file('build/intermediates/')
   delete 'build/generated/'
   delete 'build/intermediates/'
   delete 'build/outputs/'
   delete 'build/tmp/'
}
```

By executing `ReleaseLib` task using `Gradle wrapper` from terminal, I will have Lib-`MobileFramework-Android` folder includes `javadoc` and `myLib.jar`. That is exactly what I expected.

```
MobileFramework-Android.zip -> javadoc, myLib.jar, MyApp -> TestApp.apk
```

I use `ship.io` as continues integration framework. When I execute releaseLib task from there, javadoc is under MobileFramework-Android folder as expected, but .jar file is not under folder rather outside it. So I have following:

```
MobileFramework-Android.zip -> javadoc, TestApp (Empty folder)
myLib.jar
TestApp.apk
```

Why is that and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

We do move some files to the artifacts directory, including the .jar file. I confirmed this in the most recent build on your account, the 'libMobileTagging.jar' file is in the artifacts directory. If you're interested in moving it to a specific location, you can run a command in your gradle task to move create/move the directory you want to save.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Edwin, yes .jar file in specific folder as well as apk file in specific folder.

Comment: @Edwin, Read your answer from few days ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524031/generate-jar-file-and-javadoc-in-ship-io.  `upload artifacts as soon as the Gradle task completes.` In my gradle task I moved the file to specific directory, but when you create file in Artifacts, then what can I do (since you wait until gradle tasks complete)?